# rpc shutdown command from linux to windows server 2012 - connection refused

Tags: linux, windows, shutdown, rpc

I am needing to restart a windows server from a linux server.

The error i get is: (i have replaced ip address with xx )

```
Could not connect to server xx.xx.xx.xx
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

it fails with that result no matter what.

The commands i have tried are:

```
net rpc shutdown -I xx.xx.xx.xx -f -U user%password

net rpc shutdown -I xx.xx.xx.xx -f -U domain/user%password

net rpc shutdown -f -I xx.xx.xx.xx -W domain.local -U user%password
```

I have also tried taking out the password, after executing the command it then asks for a password. If i type the password in it still fails with the NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

It is the Administrator account im trying to login with.

I have temp disabled firewall altogether for a second while testing.

Very lost and its driving me mad. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Now i am getting a Connection failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED